# javascript moment.js script not working quite right

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The code below: if ( exDate.isBefore( today ) || !exDate) --> the !exDate code doesn't work. Can anyone help me? I am trying to caculate the ef FEE based on the expires date. http://verlager.com/account-pure.php The code has to include ** member > "" **

```
function calcEntryFee( elem ) {
var idx, member, exDate, today, fee;

elem = elem || {};
if ( /^[PEMX](\d+)$/.test( elem.id ) ) {
    idx = RegExp.$1;
} else {
    return false;
}

member = getMemberData( jQuery( '#P' + idx ).val() );
mmfee = parseFloat( jQuery( '#M' + idx ).val() );
//exDate = moment( member.Expires, 'YYYY.MM.DD' );
exDate = member && member.Expires && member.Expires !== '' ? moment( member.Expires, 'YYYY.MM.DD' ) : null
today = moment();
fee = '';

if ( (!exDate || !exDate.isValid() || exDate.isBefore( today )) && (member.Name > '')) {fee = 5;} // this just doesn't work.

if (!exDate) 
{
    fee = 5;
} else if ( exDate.isSameOrAfter( today ) ) {
    fee = 3;
} else if ( ! member.Expires && mmfee > 0 ) {
    fee = 0;
} 

// Updates the entry fee input value.
jQuery( '#E' + idx ).val( fee );

return fee;
}
```

Comment: try changing order and adding valid check: `if ( !exDate || !exDate.isValid() || exDate.isBefore( today ))`

Comment: very close I believe. But it has to include non-blank member only.

Comment: In other words, the criteria for 5 has to be a non-blank member input field

Comment: then just do something like `exDate = member && member.Expires && member.Expires !== '' ? moment( member.Expires, 'YYYY.MM.DD' ) : null` - that will also make sense of the `!exDate` condition which you could have removed otherwise

Comment: I posted your code and tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: I want to add a conditional such that the blank names don't get charged $5. I tried: if ( (!exDate || !exDate.isValid() || exDate.isBefore( today )) && (member.Name >= '')) {fee = 5;} but the " && (member.Name >= '') didn't work. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. I ended up using [moment-range](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range). Based on your code sample, perhaps you could check the expiration like this:

```
import Moment from 'moment'
import { extendMoment } from 'moment-range'

const moment = extendMoment(Moment)

export default (expires) => {
  const momentExpires = moment(expires, 'YYYY.MM.DD')
  const now = moment()

  const expirationCheck = moment.range(now.format(), momentExpires.format())

  return {
    expired: expirationCheck.valueOf() < 0
  }
}
```